# Solving of Linear Systems using Gaussian Elimination

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the matrix equation

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&-2\\-1&1&2\\0&6&1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix} = \lambda \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}$$

where x, y, z are unknowns and λ is a constant.

Rewrite the matrix equation as a homogeneous system of linear equations and solve the homogeneous linear system

I've attempted the question by using Gaussian Elimination and have arrived at the following row-echelon form

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&3-λ&0\\0&3-λ&3&0\\0&0&3-(1-λ)(3-λ)&0\end{bmatrix}$$

which leaves me with only the trivial solution where x = 0, y = 0 and z = 0. Can some one help me verify that this linear system only has the trivial solution? Or have I missed out any of the solution. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, $Ax= \lambda x$, equivalently $(A- \lambda)x= 0$ has the "trivial solution", x= 0.  That is the only solution **unless** the matrix $A- \lambda$ is "singular"- has determinant 0.  So **first** find the values of $\lambda$ that make the determinant 0.

Comment: If the trivial solution can be derived from Gaussian Elimination, is it still necessary to find the values of λ?

Comment: Hi @Moo! Would you mind sharing with me how you got your that reduced low echelon form?

Comment: The point, Joseph, is that there are one or more values of $\lambda$ for which there are non-trivial solutions. Your job is to find those values of $\lambda$.

Comment: $Ax = \lambda x$ means $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue and $x$ is/are the eigenvector(s) correct? Then the problem is equivalent to solving the eigenvalue problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a partial answer, as others have pointed out the matrix $A-\lambda I$ needs to be singular for the nontrivial solutions to exist. That is it's determinant must be zero.

$$\left| {A - \lambda I} \right| = {\lambda ^3} - 3{\lambda ^2} - 8\lambda  - 2 = 0$$

Solving the cubic by hand is not trivial but you can plot it and get approximate roots.

[image]

$$ \left| {A - \lambda I} \right| = 0 \Rightarrow \begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {{\lambda _1} =  + 4.7664} \\ 
  {{\lambda _2} =  - 1.4836} \\ 
  {{\lambda _3} =  - 0.2828} 
\end{array}$$

Then for each $ \lambda _i $ solve the equations

$$ \left[ {A - {\lambda _i}I} \right]\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {{x}} \\ 
  {{y}} \\ 
  {{z}} 
\end{array}} \right] = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  0 \\ 
  0 \\ 
  0 
\end{array}} \right] $$
using your favorite method to get the (approximate) non-trivial solutions.

Comment: Hi, May I know how you got the cubic equation? Because I seem to have gotten another one.

Comment: $$A - \lambda I = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {1 - \lambda }&1&{ - 2} \\ 
  { - 1}&{1 - \lambda }&2 \\ 
  0&6&{1 - \lambda } 
\end{array}} \right]$$
Expand determinant along bottom row:
$$  - 6\left[ {2 - 2\lambda  - 2} \right] + \left( {1 - \lambda } \right)\left[ {1 - 2\lambda  + {\lambda ^2} + 1} \right] $$
Which simplifies to:
$$ 8\lambda  + 3{\lambda ^2} - {\lambda ^3} + 2 $$
Since this should be equal to zero, you can multiply throughout by $-1$ to get the above cubic.